# How to disable "From email address" for unauthorized users?

Tags: civimail, extension, email, permissions, roles

If we define "From email address" then any user can use any of these addresses to send an email through the CiviCRM. Is there any way to disable the selection of these addresses for specific roles?

Answer (score 4):

You can try following:

- Go to Administer-> Customize data and Screens-> Navigation Menu and  select Mailing.
- From mailing option, do right click and edit on 'From Email Address'.
- In the next window, you can choose permission to that particular menu under 'Mailing'.
- After choosing permission for menu, assign that permission to the role you want.

With this you can give permission to single submenu.

If you want restrict unauthorized user, simply do not assign the permission to anonymous user

Comment: Clever idea! Have you tested it?

Comment: Thanks Rohan but we refer to the "From email adress" functionality on the sending email process and not to the access on the configuration form or menu.

Comment: Ok....................

Answer (score 3):

I write a first approach extension to achieve this question. Needs more test and go further but I think it's a good start. We already have the extension running in our production environment.

Feel free to try it.

https://civicrm.org/extensions/from-email-address-permission

https://github.com/babu-cat/cat.babu.fromemailaddresspermission

Comment: Extension is currently unmantained. See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/198 to follow a core or hook solution to this need.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good idea - but one that's not currently implemented in CiviCRM.  If you have access to a developer you could write an extension to achieve this.  You might also submit it to the CiviCRM [paid issue queue](https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue).

Comment: Seems like just adding a permission (I know easier said than done) like "Send email using Site From Email address" would work. IF the user/role doesn't have that permission then they are only allowed to send using their email address.

Comment: @frTommy - I agree, if the goal is to achieve all-or-nothing functionality, this isn't so bad.  When I saw this, the first thing I thought was that someone will want people to send as any "From" address EXCEPT for a particular one - coding the permission on a per-address level gets hairy!

Comment: I found some related unfinished work at [ACL or Drupal permission to allow certain roles to choose between the "From email addresses"](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-5491) aproaching to the solution. I dont know if @kasper-souren could tell us something about it?